# Answering my Own Question using Links provided in a Link Only Answer?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23849377/825757) today and received two link only answers. (One of which has since been deleted.)

The links were able to help me find a solution, however, when I search SO and come across link only answers it can be frustrating for me so I took the links that were provided and created a proper [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23851464/825757) to the question.

Is this an okay practice to do? IE: Taking a link only answer and answering my own question with the link(s) provided?

Comment: The answer is of very good quality at first glimpse so you're entirely in the clear there. However if it is really a duplicate then you could have saved yourself the hassle and instead close your question as such. I prefer to leave a CW answer to my own questions detailing my result (when applicable) because I consider it very helpful to stumble upon a question-solution-sample combination myself when googling.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Link-only answers are not allowed. This has been [discussed many times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), so I won't duplicated it here.

If you want to answer your own question, it's perfectly fine to say "this is the link I got my answer from, and here are the details of how I solved it". Just don't make your answer a link-only answer as well.

And looking at the length of your answer, I'd say you have cleared that obstacle.

Comment: What do you mean by LOA?

Comment: @RobW, "LOA" is the abbreviation of "Link-Only Answer". Veedrac changed that in my post, which is fine.